# I messed up with Legacy Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, uefi

The rundown is that I bought a new laptop (Acer Aspire E 15 E5-575G-53VG) that I want to install Xubuntu on. I have two ssds, one m.2 that has Windows 10 and another SATA that I wish to install Xubuntu on.

I successfully created a Live-USB for Xubuntu using rufus. In the laptop's boot menu I could not see the USB disk. I changed the Boot mode from UEFI to Legacy and was able to successfully see the Live USB. However I discovered that Legacy mode causes issues with the Laptop's trackpad and in general is a pain because I have to switch back to UEFI to boot up windows.

So now I have one disk that boots Xubuntu in Legacy mode and another that boots Windows 10 in UEFI mode and I don't know where to go from here.

Thank you in advance for any and all help. It is very much appreciated.